# Android: Get Log without PC-Connection

Tags: android, logging

I have to debug my Android App by walking down the street and get different WiFi signals.
When the Device is connected to my PC i can get the Log easy over LogCat, but i need the Log Statements during the test outside.

Now, is there a way to get Log? something like a Log file?

If not is it possible to add a File Logger like java.util.logging.FileHandler?

Or any other suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check aLogcat application in the play store.

This will show you the logcat of the device and allows you to save it to the sd card.

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.jtb.alogcat&hl=nl

Answer (score 0):

You can catch log programatically and trace it in a view .. http://www.androidsnippets.com/how-to-capture-application-log